# jQuery dynamic height on list items

Tags: jquery

**Scenario**

I have a container (there will be more), with list items inside, each containing an image. The height of the container is dynamic relative to the height of the list items, which themselves change within a media query. The container has a min-height, so when the images are larger the idea is to adjust the size of the container, to slide down.

I'm currently getting the height of the images list item when the page loads, but this isn't great as they are quite a few images so it can take a while for it to adjust.

Unfortunately it's quite a large project and I wouldn't be able to replicate the scenario in jsfiddle exactly, I think this is close enough.

**Solution**

I need some way of getting the height of the first images' list item that loads and then making the container the same height.

**Code**

***HTML***

```
<ul class="container">
    <li class="img">
        <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/50/100" width="100%" height="100%" />
    </li>
    <li class="img">
        <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/50/100" width="100%" height="100%" />
    </li>
    <li class="img">
        <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/50/100" width="100%" height="100%" />
    </li>
...so on
</ul>
```

***CSS***

```
li {
    list-style: none;
}
.img {
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50px;
}
.container {
    border:5px solid green;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height:100px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .img {
        width: 25%; height: auto;
    }

}
```

***Js***

```
$(window).load(function() {

    $('.container').each(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            height: $('.img').height(),
            slideDown: 'fast'
        });
    }); 

});
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/ZwQu7/1/

Thankyou for your time.

Comment: Didnt get ur question..Plz be more specific...?? Do u want the container's height to be changed dynamically as of the images...

Comment: @user1145009 yes, because the images size change depending on the screen dimentions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you could do it like this :

```
$('.container').each(function() {
    $(this).find('img').load(function(){
        $(this).closest('.container').animate({
            height: $(this).height(),
            slideDown: 'fast'
        });
    })
});
```

This way you wait for the images to load (so you will know the height of the images) and animate it after that.

(The `li` won't have a height, the `img` will.)

If you only want to animate the `container` once you could check it like:

```
$('.container').each(function() {
    $(this).find('img').load(function(){
        $(this).closest('.container:not(.animated)').animate({
            height: $(this).height(),
            slideDown: 'fast'
        }).addClass('animated');
    })
});
```

But that will animate as soon as the first image is loaded and won't animate after that.

Comment: I think this is close to what i'm after, although it needs some tweaking to fit. Thankyou.

Comment: What tweaking do you need? And if this solution helped for the initial question, could you accept it?

Comment: As i pointed out in my OP, it's a fairly large project I'm working on, so the example I gave was a close as i could get to the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Images must be loaded before you can access their real dimensions, but you can use `getimagesize()` to compute the total initial size on server side (assuming you're using php).

Or if you know the size of all the images (i see you wrote 100px), you can multiply their initial number to get the total height.

Or add pixels to the container's height as images load :

```
$('.container img').on('load', function() {
    var $c = $(this).parents('.container');
    $c.css('height', (($c.height() || 0) + this.height) + 'px');
});
```

Comment: Thankyou, this could be a fall back option, but it would need to be client-side, plus the `.img` dimensions were a bit of a red herring as that was original implementation (which I need to remove).

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I managed to get working (if anyone is interested), thanks to putvande:

```
$('.container').each(function() {
    $(this).find('img').load(function(){
        $(this).closest('.container').animate({
            height: $('.img').height(),
            slideDown: 'fast'
        });
    });
});
```

Once again, thankyou all for your input. Y.